# Error Downloading an excel file from a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, material-ui, jsx

I would like to download an excel file from my react app.

I have a download button with the prop `onClick={handleExcel}`. Within my handleExcel constant I have the following code:

```
const handleExcel = () => {
        if (excel){
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = `Example.xlsx`;
            console.log(excel)
            link.href = excel;
            link.click();
        }
    };
```

The excel file is stored in the state named excel, and when console logged it outputs:
`File {name: "Test.xlsx", lastModified: 1627328001242, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 26 2021 15:33:21 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 9883, …}` so I know the file is there. However, the download itself fails as there is "no file".

I believe the issue may be with the link.href line but I am not very experienced with jsx so am quite unsure.

Would love any ideas! Thanks!

Comment: You need to set href as a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)